# ELB to tomcat https redirecting to http

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elb

So we have tomcat servers behind a AWS ELB.  Everything is working fine with https *except*  if we manually type in this address:

https://example.com/web/   This works fine...

https://example.com/web   This redirects to http

What's weird is that every other address redirects to https just fine.  it's only the root that is not working.

Im sure I did not post information for a fix,  but if someone could at least point me in a direction to look at.

There is no apache httpd in the stack, so there is no .htaccess file or mod_rewirte going on.  I think its the ELB,  but as everything else is redirecting fine, im not sure.

Comment: Try set `proxyName` and `proxyPort` in connectors configuration, see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Proxy_Support

Comment: ELBs don't do redirection on their own; perhaps you have something in your Tomcat webapps which are performing the redirects?  Which version of Tomcat are you using?  See here for a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34400627/4072843

Comment: Are you doing ssl termination on the ELB?

Comment: @dtryon  Yes we are.